# How can I set the Google Chrome Application Mode window size?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I set the Google Chrome Application Mode window size?

As per http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ I tried:

```
"GoogleChromePortable\GoogleChromePortable.exe" --app-shell-host-window-size=800x600 --app=file
://C:/temp/temp.html
```

without success:

1 Run the command

2 Resize the window to https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGOPa.png and close

3 Run the command

Expected: window 800x600

Observed: window size unchanged:

[image]

Likewise with a comma:

```
--app-shell-host-window-size=800,600
```